Full Calendar not sizing correctly on first load

Here I am trying to load the calendar as you can see it seems to be squished to the left and I am unsure why. I tried setting the width of the calendar manually when rendering it but nothing seems to work. However, when I resize the screen it goes to the normal size I want it to be
My jQuery:
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            width: 1000,
            initialView: 'timeGridWeek', // default view being week
            locale: 'en-gb',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,dayGridMonth' // displays buttons to show each view: week, day, and month
            },
            slotDuration: '00:15:00', // Each slot is 15 minutes
            slotLabelInterval: '00:15:00', // Display time labels every 15 minutes
            slotLabelFormat: { //sets the time being 2 digits   
                hour: 'numeric',
                minute: '2-digit',
                omitZeroMinute: false,
                meridiem: 'short'
            },
            slotMinTime: '08:00:00', // Start time for the slots (8:00 AM)
            slotMaxTime: '17:00:00', // End time for the slots (5:00 PM)
            selectable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            select: function(info) {
                const selectedStartTime = moment(info.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
                const fixedDuration = moment.duration('00:15:00');
                const selectedEndTime = moment(info.start).add(fixedDuration).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');

                $('#start_time').val(selectedStartTime);
                $('#end_time').val(selectedEndTime);

                $('#start_time').prop('readonly', true);
                $('#end_time').prop('readonly', true);

                $('#event_entry_modal').modal('show');
            },
            eventClick: function(info) {
                $('#eventModalLabel').text(info.event.title);
                $('#eventModalStart').text(moment(info.event.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
                $('#eventModalEnd').text(moment(info.event.end).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
                $('#eventModalNurse').text(info.event.extendedProps.nurseFirstName + ' ' + info.event.extendedProps.nurseLastName);
                $('#eventModalPatient').text(info.event.extendedProps.patientFirstName + ' ' + info.event.extendedProps.patientLastName);

                var patientProfileUrl = '/employeeProfile/' + info.event.extendedProps.patientId;

                $('#viewPatientProfile').off('click').on('click', function() {
                    window.parent.location.href = patientProfileUrl;
                });

                $('#eventModal').modal('show');
            },
            events: '/calendar/displayEvents',
            editable: true,
            hiddenDays: [0, 6],
            views: {
                dayGridMonth: {
                    selectable: false,
                    selectMirror: false
                }
            }
        });
        calendar.render();
    });

My HTML:
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-appointments">
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>


I have tried setting the screen width using js and css neither work. I tried using a set timeout on the rendering of the calendar in case it was rendering too quickly this also did not work.

Those are Bootstrap tabs, right? Then that's likely the culprit - none-active tabs have display: none applied, meaning they have no dimensions either. So when fullcalendar tries to determine how much width it has available to render itself in, it will only get a width of 0. Once you have activated that tab, and then resize, this time it will be able to read the correct value. You will either have to do the FC initialization only after the tab has been shown the first time; or trigger the window resize event when it gets shown.
